# How do determine whether Linux board is using hardware FPU or not?

Tags: linux, arm, floating-point

I am using an embedded Linux board based on a fairly old Freescale ARM chip.  How do I determine whether the Python interpreter there is using the hardware FPU on the chip or not?

My /proc/cpuinfo is:

```
Processor       : ARM926EJ-S rev 5 (v5l)
BogoMIPS        : 179.81
Features        : swp half thumb fastmult edsp java
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 5TEJ
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0x926
CPU revision    : 5
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In the ARM world from ARMv4 to ARMv7 floating-point support is called [VFP](http://www.arm.com/products/processors/technologies/vector-floating-point.php), and hardware support for it appears in the `Features` line of `/proc/cpuinfo` or in the `VFP support` log message printed by the kernel while booting. (In ARMv8 it's just "FP".)

In `/proc/cpuinfo` on an Allwinner A20 this gives:

```
Features    : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp thumbee neon vfpv3 tls vfpv4 idiva idivt vfpd32 lpae evtstrm
```

(see the various `vfp` features) and in the boot log:

```
VFP support v0.3: implementor 41 architecture 2 part 30 variant 7 rev 4
```

If VFP isn't fully supported, the kernel will instead log

```
VFP support v0.3: not present
```

or

```
VFP support v0.3: no double precision support
```

As to whether your Python interpreter is capable of using this, it appears to depend mainly on the architecture of your ARM Linux distribution. If I understand things correctly, basic Debian `armel` won't use the FPU, Debian `armhf` (and Raspbian `armhf`) will; the older Debian `arm` variant used FPU instructions, but these were emulated if the hardware didn't support them. On `armel` you can install kernels or C libraries with FPU support (although no such C library appears to be available in the Debian archives).

Comment: Thanks Stephen, very detailed answer.  My /proc/cpuinfo is below, so from that looks like I am definitely not using hardware FP?  Processor       : ARM926EJ-S rev 5 (v5l)
BogoMIPS        : 179.81
Features        : swp half thumb fastmult edsp java
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 5TEJ
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0x926
CPU revision    : 5

Comment: It would appear so, at least your kernel doesn't support your FPU. There is a VFP9-S in the ARM926EJ-S, but I don't know if there's a mainstream kernel which would support the combination...

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
awk '$1 == "fpu" { print $3 ; }' /proc/cpuinfo
```

which give

```
yes
yes
```

you cant refine with

```
 awk '$1 == "fpu" { print $3 ; exit ;}' /proc/cpuinfo
```

to have only one yes.

A mere grep would yield (flags line abbridged)

```
fpu         : yes
fpu_exception       : yes
flags               : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtr ...
fpu         : yes
fpu_exception       : yes
flags               : fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtr ...
```

unfortunatly I don't have a FPU less linux to make the test, maybe a rapsberry owner ?

Comment: `/proc/cpuinfo` on my FPU-less Seagate DockStar doesn't even have a `fpu` line, so one probably needs to check if the line is absent *or* contains `no` to be sure that no FPU is being used.