# What debian ARCH should I use for armv7l kernel?

Tags: debootstrap

```
debootstrap --arch=ARCH stable debian-stable http://ftp.debian.org/debian/
```

`debootstrap` requires architecture to be set. Debian supports `armel` and `armhf` architectures of ARM 32-bit family. Which one to choose for `armv7l` Linux? (in case it's generally supported at all).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both will work, but [`armhf`](https://wiki.debian.org/ArchitectureSpecificsMemo#armhf) is a better fit if you have floating point: “`armv7` with VFPv3-D16 floating point”. (`armv7l` is little-endian v7.)

To determine whether you have appropriate floating point support, look for `vfpv3` in the “Features” line in `/proc/cpuinfo`. See also [How do determine whether Linux board is using hardware FPU or not?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/184874/86440)

Comment: How could I check if I have `VFPv3-D16`?

Comment: Look for `vfpv3` in the “Features” line in `/proc/cpuinfo` (see [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/185070/86440)).